# Connect HP laptop to TV with HDMI

Tags: hdmi

I have an HP Pavilion with Ubuntu 16.04.  When connecting to my Samsung smart TV I see the desktop background  perfectly. But nothing else (movies for instance) which I run on the laptop shows up on the TV screen - only the desktop background.

"Mirror Display" is grayed out and I can't choose it - in case that is the solution.

Comment: drag the windows to the other screen?  It probably is locked to "extend screen" for what ever reason

Comment: Can you update your question with your HP Pavilion model number and Samsung smart tv model number?

Comment: You cannot use "mirror display" with devices having different resolutions.